# How to make an UICollection view with items moving left and right when swiping?

Tags: swift, swipe

I want to make an UICollection view where you can move items left and right.
It should look like the app amazon video.
I know how to make an UICollection view but it just moves vertically.

Comment: Did you look at the layout settings?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the default `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`
 there is a property called `scrollDirection` on the layout. You can set this property to `UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal`.